# ScrollView SmoothScrollBy not showing the last item

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-scrollview

**UPDATE For XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100">
    <!--App Bar Layout Pane-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="@drawable/AppBarBackground"
        android:weightSum="100">

    <!--Unrelated XML Code-->

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--App Bar Layout Pane end-->
    <!--Body Pane-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="93"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@drawable/AppBackground">
    <!--Left Pane-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="37"
            android:background="@color/whiteWithAlpha75">

    <!--Unrelated XML Code-->

        </LinearLayout>
    <!--Left Pane end-->
    <!--Right Pane-->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="43">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="100">
            <!--Right Pane Header-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:weightSum="100"
                    android:background="@color/whiteWithAlpha10"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Item(s)"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="24"
                        android:textColor="@color/grayDark"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeXSmall" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Unit Price"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="17"
                        android:textColor="@color/grayDark"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeXSmall" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Quantity"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="28"
                        android:textColor="@color/grayDark"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeXSmall" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Discount"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="16"
                        android:textColor="@color/grayDark"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeXSmall" />
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Total"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/fontFamily"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="15"
                        android:textColor="@color/grayDark"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeXSmall" />
                </LinearLayout>
            <!--Right Pane Header end-->
            <!--Right Pane Item Selected-->
                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollItemSelectedArea"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="92"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:background="@color/whiteWithAlpha15">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/llItemSelectedArea"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            <!--Right Pane Item Selected end-->
            <!--Right Pane Functions-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="39"
                    android:weightSum="100">

    <!--Unrelated XML Code-->

                </LinearLayout>
            <!--Right Pane Functions end-->
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    <!--Right Pane end-->
    </LinearLayout>
<!--Body Pane end-->
</LinearLayout>
```

---

When the items on the list reached the end of scrollview height, it should do the scrolling to show the last item selected, I am calling the smoothScrollBy every item selection. But when I have for example 6 items and my scrollview can only hold 5 items on screen, it is not scrolling up for the 6th item. And when I add another item, it shows now the 6th item but the 7th item just replaced the 6th item from being hidden. My scrollview height is matched_parent and no overlapping layout on bottom so there is no place for the last item to hide. I don't know if there is an extra space in scroll view.

How can I fix this issue?

This is where I add the new item

```
    public void renderItemSelected(ENT_TransactionItems entityTransactionItem, string displayName)
    {
        entityTransactionItemList.Add(entityTransactionItem);

        View vNewView = activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Layout_ItemSelected, llItemSelected, false);

        TextView tvItemName = vNewView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvItemName);
        TextView tvItemAmount = vNewView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvItemPrice);
        EditText etItemQuantity = vNewView.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.tvItemQuantity);
        Button btnDiscount = vNewView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDiscount);
        TextView tvTotal = vNewView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvTotal);

        //other code

        llItemSelected.AddView(vNewView);
        viewList.Add(vNewView);

        scrollItemSelectedArea.SmoothScrollBy(0, llItemSelected.Height);
    }
```

This is the sample image

[image]

Comment: Show your xml code with the ScrollView

Comment: I updated the code, removed some unrelated xml codes. Some remains for others to check layout_weight.

Comment: Add this to the ScrollView and check if it works android:fillViewport="true" then

Comment: I tried to change the NestedScrollVIew to ScrollView since fillViewPort is not present in Nested. But still the problem is present. Last item is still at the bottom hidden from screen. ScrollView only scrolled to the 2nd item from last

Comment: I don't know if this is a good answer but I solved it through adding paddingBottom to linear layout.

Comment: New problem occured, I can scroll the scroll view to the bottom leaving a blank space. PaddingBottom only pushed up the last item